# PHP Echo out whole page if verified

Tags: php, security, session, html

What's the best way to show a whole webpage if and only if the permission is granted(i.e Session set)?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        echo "<html>Huge HTML Page with secret content</html>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<html>Sorry, access not granted!</html>";
```

It seems a little unclean to me to echo a whole html page but what's a better way?

Comment: Reverse the logic and break out of PHP

Comment: do a 403 response.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Won't you usually still need the `html` tag if the user isn't permitted to view the page? Just change the contents of your `body` tag.

Comment: Yes, you would also need the html tag if access is not granted. Sorry for the misconception.

Comment: @Dominik what I mean is something like this: https://pastebin.com/3nAa95Ys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    echo "Sorry, access not granted!";
    exit;
}
?>

<html>...
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need echo, which requires everything to be inside a string. Instead, turn off the php processing for that part of the file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
?>
<html>Huge HTML Page with secret content</html>
<?php
    }
    else {
?>
<html><body>No soup for you!</body></html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: That's an interesting way but looks great. Thanks.